# magento 2 header

Tags: magento2, image, header

I have a fresh Magento2 working and  I am using `Luma` as my template.

**I want to add a  costume image on the header that goes across the template, behind the logo.**

Firebug directs me to:

```
page-header pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css
```

I realize this is static location, so, I am not suppose to edit it.

where shouldI start? I just want edit the `default luma theme` and I don't want add another costume theme. Since I am using the `github` the templates are stored in `frontend/Magento`

Answer (score 1):

go to

`frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_theme.less`

override the css by simple adding these line

```
.logo {
   img {
     max-height: inherit;
    // add here you want to add just like css
   }
}
```

for adding the background in header

```
.page-header {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

for adding the background image

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url("../images/cart_prod1.jpg");

     }
```

Comment: I tried it didnt work. thank you though. looking at the _theme.less - i dont see how this would work? this looks looks nothing like what _theme.less looking for...

Comment: after tried did you `depoly-content` again? and `var/view-processed` folder

Comment: yes i did. I added it to bottom of the  _theme.less. depoly-content, cleared cache...perhaps you can provide something more simple if you dont mind. say i want to change the background color of the header instead of adding an image.

Comment: added the simple code for adding the background color for header.

Comment: Thank you I was able to achieve this by going to app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less: added "background-color: #000;" .page-header { which already exists. is it possible to call in image from there

Comment: add the code for adding background image for header.